# HTML5 arrow keys not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html

**Hello everyone,**

I'm currently having issues making the arrow keys working correctly while pressing [space] key. Everything is working whle holding [space] key and one of the arrow keys. But if I try to press [space] and hold [up] and [left] at the same time , it will go straigh to the top of the screen as if the [left] key wasn't even pressed (it should move diagonally to the top left corner). This is only happening while pressing [space]. 
I'd like to use this key for shooting bullets later on.

Is there something wrong in my code? Or is it some kind of bug?

Apologies for my bad english :/ ..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="568" height="262">
        </canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas;
var ctx;
var dx = 0.5;
var dy = 0.5;
var x = 284;
var y = 130;
var WIDTH = 568;
var HEIGHT = 262;
var keys = new Array();

function circle(x,y,r) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
  ctx.fill();
}

function rect(x,y,w,h) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(x,y,w,h);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}

function clear() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    window.addEventListener('keydown',doKeyDown,true);
    window.addEventListener('keyup',doKeyUp,true);
    return setInterval(draw, 1);
}

function draw() {
    move();
    clear();
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    rect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);

    // player ///
    ctx.fillStyle = "purple";
    circle(x, y, 20);

}

function doKeyDown(evt)
{
    keys[evt.keyCode] = true;
    evt.preventDefault();   // Prevents the page to scroll up/down while pressing arrow keys
}

function doKeyUp(evt){
    keys[evt.keyCode] = false;
}

function move() {
        if (32 in keys && keys[32]){
            ; // fire bullets
        }
        if (38 in keys && keys[38]){ //up
            y -= dy;
        }
        if (40 in keys && keys[40]){ //down
            y += dy;
        }
        if (37 in keys && keys[37]){ //left
                x -= dx;
        }
        if (39 in keys && keys[39]){ //right
                x += dx;
        }
}

init();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Odds are this is nothing to do with your code. Many keyboards, to save cost, are not capable of supporting every combination of 3 or more keys at once, and are specifically wired to support combinations that are in common use (such as Ctrl+Alt+Del). The phenomenon is known as "ghosting".

See [this page from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx) for an expanded explanation.

Comment: you may be right, I just tried the same key combination in my old game I created couple of years ago in allegro and I can see that it's also not working.. 
At least it's working when pressing W,S,A,D and [space] key.

Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (I found the issue but not the solution)  the key codes for up and left follow each other. so do down and right. The fact that the key codes follow each other seems to be the issue. if you set A to move player UP and B to move player DOWN, then press A+B+spaceBar the same issue occurs. but when the key codes are different (e.g. wasd) the three button press works. using WASD might seem like a good idea but wait until someone using a French keyboard plays your game. 
Any way I wrote this hoping that someone would find a work around.